# How do i change a readable date and time - such as 01/01/2011 to MySQL UNIX DATETIME (2001-01-01 22:30)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datetime, codeigniter

Im using a [JQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) (datetimepicker actually) and would like the date (and time) to appear in a user friendly way such as = 01/02/2011 20:30 on the page when the user has selected their date and time, but then be able to insert it into my database as MYSQL DATETIME ( 2011-02-01 20:30 ).

I've had a good luck around but it seems most people want to do the reverse of what i want.
Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: MySQL Datetime !== Unix Datetime. Confusing headline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
($datetime contains the input value)
$datetime = date( 'Y-m-d H:i', strtotime( $datetime ) );
```

This uses PHP's built-in wrapper around `strtotime()` to parse the date expression into a Unix timestamp, then re-format it in a way that MySQL can handle.